# How much XM clusters around portals?

Tags: ingress

How much XM is generated around a portal when it's left alone for awhile?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A portal generates 10% of it current energy as XM about once every 15-20 minutes.

This means that a high level portal that is almost dead has almost the same XM yield as an unclaimed portal. This mechanic is added to encourage you to recharge your portals!

---

For example, my desk portal usually has 30k points of Energy. So, I'd get about 3,000 XM every 15-20 minutes.

Of course, this changes if a portal is weak. For example, a nearby portal has 2k points of energy out of it's max 10k. This portal will yield me about 200 XM / 20 minutes.

<sup>[[source](http://decodeingress.me/2013/06/25/xm-and-you-2-knowing-your-power-source-better/)]</sup>